# Why does one argument need to be quoted but not the other?

Tags: elisp-macros, quote

In the following code I have a reproducible example of strange behavior (the macro body is probably not important):

```
(setq annoying-commands ())

(defmacro add-annoying-arrows-advice (cmd alternatives &optional evil-cmd evil-alternatives)
  `(progn
     (add-to-list 'annoying-commands (quote ,cmd))
     (put (quote ,cmd) 'aa--alts ,alternatives)
     (put (quote ,cmd) 'aa--evil-alts ,evil-alternatives)
     (put (quote ,cmd) 'aa--evil-cmd ,evil-cmd)
     (defadvice ,cmd (before annoying-arrows activate)
       (when annoying-arrows-mode
         (aa--maybe-complain (quote ,cmd))))))

(add-annoying-arrows-advice next-line 
'(ace-jump-mode) evil-next-visual-line '(evil-search-backward))
```

Evaulating this buffer gives the error:

`Symbol's value as variable is void: evil-next-visual-line`

This is a shame because I'd like to leave the third argument to the defmacro, namely `evil-next-visual-line` unquoted, just like `next-line` (the first argument) is.

Some really flaky behavior shows if I do the following:

`(add-annoying-arrows-advice evil-next-visual-line '(smart-up) 'evil-next-visual-line '(evil-find-char-backward))`

Now all of a sudden having `evil-next-visual-line` as an unquoted argument is okay!

How could this possibly be?

Comment: Emacs version 25.0.50.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see an issue. Just macroexpand your stuff and you'll see the obvious errors:

```
(add-annoying-arrows-advice
 next-line
 '(ace-jump-mode)
 evil-next-visual-line
 '(evil-search-backward))
;; =>
(progn (add-to-list (quote annoying-commands)
                    (quote next-line))
       (put (quote next-line)
            (quote aa--alts)
            (quote (ace-jump-mode)))
       (put (quote next-line)
            (quote aa--evil-alts)
            (quote (evil-search-backward)))
       (put (quote next-line)
            (quote aa--evil-cmd)
            evil-next-visual-line)
       (defadvice next-line (before annoying-arrows activate)
         (when annoying-arrows-mode (aa--maybe-complain (quote next-line)))))

(add-annoying-arrows-advice
 evil-next-visual-line
 '(smart-up)
 'evil-next-visual-line
 '(evil-find-char-backward))
;; =>
(progn (add-to-list (quote annoying-commands)
                    (quote evil-next-visual-line))
       (put (quote evil-next-visual-line)
            (quote aa--alts)
            (quote (smart-up)))
       (put (quote evil-next-visual-line)
            (quote aa--evil-alts)
            (quote (evil-find-char-backward)))
       (put (quote evil-next-visual-line)
            (quote aa--evil-cmd)
            (quote evil-next-visual-line))
       (defadvice evil-next-visual-line (before annoying-arrows activate)
         (when annoying-arrows-mode (aa--maybe-complain (quote evil-next-visual-line)))))
```

Comment: God, stupid mistake it seems. Will it be fixed by      `(put (quote ,cmd) 'aa--evil-cmd (quote ,evil-cmd))`? Probably.

Comment: _______Probably:)

Comment: Yes, that was it. God how stupid I am.

Comment: Btw., I got the pretty macro expand with keys 'xfM' from https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy.